# Adding a test project to supplement an existing project

Tags: cmake

I am currently helping to migrate a group of visual studio projects to use CMake.  Currently all the projects have been migrated and are building successfully.  However, we have yet to re-incorporate our unit tests.

Is there a way to create a separate executable for unit tests without having to recompile all the source files of the dependent project?  In other words, is there a simple way to allow the test project to link to object files produced by the dependent project?

Here is an example structure of two projects, application and test:

```
Foo
  bar.cpp
  baz.cpp
  main.cpp // entry for app executable

TestFoo
  test-bar.cpp // requires linking to bar
  test-baz.cpp // requires linking to baz
  main.cpp // entry for test executable
```

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614137/avoid-recompilation-of-common-object-files-with-cmake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a CMake version >= 2.8.8, you can use the Objects Library:

```
add_library(bar OBJECT a.c)
```

Then *link* (not really linking in fact) it to foo:

```
add_executable(foo main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:bar>)
```

and to bar:

```
add_executable(testfoo main.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:bar>)
```

The objects library doesn't creates a library file but act somehow as a shared object. You can find more information here: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library

Comment: Doesn't seem to work:CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:197 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "lib" of type OBJECT_LIBRARY may not be linked into another
  target.  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables
  with the ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed my example, sorry :)

Comment: Is there a way to use the `target_link_libraries` with the object target?  It seems I get an error, but then we're back to the same issue of having to duplicate a cmake command over multiple targets (in this case, `foo` and `testfoo`).

Comment: Nevermind, the initial issue was simply having to re-compile the same source, which is solved by your answer.  Thanks!